# Encoding fails when marshalling string via COM Interop in C# (double UTF8 encoding?)

Tags: c#, unicode, marshalling, com-interop, autodesk-navisworks

I'm writing a plugin for Autodesk Navisworks, trying to pass a C# unicode string to a property on a COM object. However, the string is encoded incorrectly somewhere in the process.

```
var property = ...;
property.Name = "中文";   // becomes "??"
property.Value = "中文"; // OK
```

"中文" comes out as "??" in the user interface, whereas strings limited to ASCII work just fine (e.g. "abcd"). Furthermore, setting the Value-property (a VARIANT) on the same object works just fine, but not the Name.

Further exploration leads me to try encoding the string "ä" as utf-8:

```
C3 A4
```

and somehow "encoding" this into a (unicode) string:

```
property.Name = "\u00c3\u00a4"; // shows up as "ä"
```

Surprisingly this seemed to work.

This led me to try the following:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("中文abcd");
char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    chars[i] = (char)bytes[i];
string s = new string(chars);
```

However, when I use this trying to encode "中文abcd" I only get the first character "中" in the GUI. Yet, with "äabcd" I get more than one character again...

What is happening here? How can I get around the problem? Is it a marshalling problem (e.g. incorrectly specified encoding in the COM Interop)? Or perhaps some weird code inside the application? If it's a marshalling problem, can I modify it for this property only?

Comment: could you dump the output in hex? I think I have an idea where this is going...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `Name` was an "internal" string, and I should have used the property `UserName` for text displayed in the GUI.

I.e. I changed:

```
var property = ...;
property.Name = "中文";   // becomes "??"
property.Value = "中文"; // OK
```

to this:

```
var property = ...;
property.UserName = "中文";   // OK!
property.Value = "中文"; // OK
```

which worked. Presumably UserName is implicitly set from Name internally in some way ignoring or mishandling the encoding.